# I am trying to recompile xbmc on debian Linux getting this error need

Tags: android, linux, xbmc

```
buttler@buttler:~/kodi$ **make -C tools/depends/target/cmakebuildsys BUILD_DIR=$HOME/kodi-build**<br/>
make: Entering directory '/home/buttler/kodi/tools/depends/target/cmakebuildsys'<br/>
mkdir -p /home/buttler/kodi-build<br/>
cd /home/buttler/kodi-build; /home/buttler/android-tools/xbmc-depends/x86_64-linux-gnu-native/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/buttler/android-tools/xbmc-depends/arm-linux-androideabi-21-debug/share/Toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/buttler/android-tools/xbmc-depends/arm-linux-androideabi-21-debug -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DENABLE_INTERNAL_CROSSGUID=OFF -DENABLE_INTERNAL_FFMPEG=OFF  /home/buttler/kodi<br/>
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.2.1<br/>
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.2.1<br/>
-- The ASM compiler identification is GNU<br/>
-- Found assembler: /usr/bin/cc<br/>
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++<br/>
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- broken<br/>
CMake Error at /home/buttler/android-tools/xbmc-depends/x86_64-linux-gnu-native/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:45 (message):<br/>
  The C++ compiler

    "/usr/bin/c++"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:<br/>
    Change Dir: /home/buttler/kodi-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp<br/>    
    Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_39029/fast"<br/>
    make[1]: Entering directory '/home/buttler/kodi-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'<br/>
    /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_39029.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_39029.dir/build<br/>
    make[2]: Entering directory '/home/buttler/kodi-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'<br/>
    Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_39029.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o<br/>
    /usr/bin/c++    -DANDROID -D__ANDROID_API__=21 -fexceptions -funwind-tables -fstack-<br/>protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -fPIC -DPIC -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a9 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -frtti -g -D_DEBUG  -I/home/buttler/android-tools/xbmc-depends/arm-linux-androideabi-21-debug/include/android-21 -isystem /home/buttler/android-tools/xbmc-depends/arm-linux-androideabi-21-debug/include    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_39029.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /home/buttler/kodi-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx<br/>
    c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mfloat-abi=softfp’<br/>
    c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mfpu=neon’<br/>
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_39029.dir/build.make:66: CMakeFiles/cmTC_39029.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o] Error 1<br/>
    make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/buttler/kodi-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'<br/>
    make[1]: ** [Makefile:121: cmTC_39029/fast] Error 2<br/>
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/buttler/kodi-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'<br/>

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!<br/>
See also "/home/buttler/kodi-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".<br/>
See also "/home/buttler/kodi-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".<br/>
make: *** [Makefile:17: all] Error 1<br/>
make: Leaving directory '/home/buttler/kodi/tools/depends/target/cmakebuildsys'<br/>
```

Comment: Hi, could you please give more information? The title is cut off and you have no real context or question, just log output in your question body. Please increase your effort for this question.

Comment: `-mfloat-abi` and `-mfpu` are ARM options as described in `man gcc`. You have to get a cross-compiler or configure the build system to target x86.

Comment: i am actually building or recompiling xbmc android app in linux source link is https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc/blob/master/docs/README.Android.md#32-configure-android-sdk